# Elgg install error: Your server does not support automatic testing of the rewrite rules and your browser does not support checking via JavaScript

Tags: php, apache, elgg

I'm trying to install elgg on my **apache2** server but I keep getting the error when I get to the installation page ***elgg/install.php?step=requirements***:

> Your server does not support automatic testing of the rewrite rules and your browser does not support checking via JavaScript. You can continue the installation, but you may experience problems with your site. You can manually test the rewrite rules by clicking this link: test. You will see the word success if the rules are working.

I already have done:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html -R
```

and even:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html -R
```

but to no success. I Keep getting the warning. What am I not doing? I am able to create a database, and even log into PHPMyAdmin, though.

Thank you all in advance.

> elgg-2.3.3

**PHP**

> PHP 7.0.19-1 (cli) (built: May 11 2017 14:04:47) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>      with Zend OPcache v7.0.19-1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

**APACHE**

> Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
>   Server built:   2017-01-25T22:59:26

**Kali Linux**

> Linux rev 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing permission of elgg-config folder.

```
chmod 777 elgg-config
```

if you are using nginx

```
location = /rewrite.php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /install.php;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that @enRaiser then `sudo service apache2 restart`, but same results.

Comment: did you run composer update. IF not learn what is it . and run

Comment: location = /rewrite.php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /install.php;
        }

Answer (score 2):

Read this page. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
Go to elgg folder. The rewrite rules for Elgg is in the file .htaccess